# permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION Red line .. or Manifest merger failed with multiple errors

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a beginner and I use Android Studio. A problem keeps on bothers me.

It keeps on showing Error message

```
Element uses-permission#com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES at AndroidManifest.xml:46:2-95 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:35:5-98

Element uses-permission#android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION at AndroidManifest.xml:47:2-78 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:22:5-81

Element uses-permission#android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION at AndroidManifest.xml:48:2-76 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:23:5-79

tools:replace specified at line:67 for attribute tools:value, but no new value specified

Element meta-data#com.google.android.gms.version at AndroidManifest.xml:85:9-87:39 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:81:10-83:69

Validation failed, exiting

Manifest merger failed with multiple errors
```

also Red Line

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"

Mock locations should only be requested in a test or debug-specific manifest file (typically src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml) less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Using a mock location provider (by requiring the permission android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION) should only be done in debug builds (or from tests). In Gradle projects, that means you should only request this permission in a test or debug source set specific manifest file.  To fix this, create a new manifest file in the debug folder and move the <uses-permission> element there. A typical path to a debug manifest override file in a Gradle project is src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml.
```

I've tried:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.Hi.Hello">



<application
        android:name="com.Hi.Hello.app.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
        tools:replace="value,icon,label,theme">
```

but I could not solve. permission problem  and  Manifest merger failed with multiple errors about Help !!

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.Hi.Hello"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':bFAB')
    compile project(':bPhotoView')
    compile project(':bSlidingLayer')
    compile project(':bSlidingMenu')
    compile project(':bUniversalImageLoader')
    compile project(':bUtils')
    compile project(':bTwoWayView')
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile project(':kakaoSDK')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.2.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-cache-4.2.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.2.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsoup-1.7.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.gcm:gcm-server:1.0.0'
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have another manifest.xml (maybe from one of the dependent projects) that declares those same permissions and causing these errors.

Comment: I'll look it up  Thank you

Comment: Have you defined the permission ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION somewhere? Have you tried to put the permission only in the Android Manifest of the Debug-Buildtype? This is the suggestion from the error description.

Comment: Thank you ,  i dont this problem ..

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is like the error message describes:

```
tools:replace specified at line:67 for attribute tools:value, but no new value specified
```

In your application-tag you do not set a replacement-attribute for the "value"-tag:

```
<application
    android:name="com.Hi.Hello.app.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
    tools:replace="value,icon,label,theme">
```

As I do not know an "android:value"-tag in the application-tag, I would recommend to change the tools:replace-node:

```
    tools:replace="icon,label,theme"
```

More information about the manifest merger could be found here:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger

Comment: formerly no "value" ..  but continuously Errors msg ... so add value

Comment: Thank you for letting me know